# AndroidManifest.xml not found

Tags: ionic-framework

When I run `$ ionic cordova emulate android`, the error is displayed:

[image]

[image]

What have solution to solve this ?

`SDK` is version: `28.0.3`

Comment: Try to create a new project and copy paste your old project  `src` folder into new project

Comment: update your cordova to 8.0.0. somewhere i read ionic 4 supports cordova 8.0.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Error caused by the wrong name of your project's folder. Or do you have a folder known as `{project name}`?